# Overlapping the textarea or text over the image HTML, CSS in angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, overlapping

I am creating a website for the study.

While I am creating text area and some form works,

I have no idea about how to overlap the image and text.

This is one example what I want to do below
[This is example of the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfhOC.png)

How to overlap the textarea or text over the image like the uploaded image??

Thanks!

```
<div class = "container">
   <img src = '/assets/img/Iphone.png' alt="Snow" width = "300" height = "530" style = "margin-top: -1300px; margin-left:-200px">
   <div class="centered" style = "margin-top: -800px; margin-left: -10px; padding: 10px;" src = '/assets/img/Iphone.png'>hello</div>
</div>
```

[Here's second example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTg1y.png)

I want to make a background color for "hello" as the second example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

position the element to be on the bottom right of the parent

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.wrapper textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper .counter {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div class="counter">Foo</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No clue what you are talking about an image

Comment: I edited what I am doing for it. If you check the second example I uploaded, the text with blue background color over the image. Is there any way to add a background color over the image?

Comment: I tried style = "background-color: blue", but It wasn't worked :(

Comment: So use a background image and put elements on top of it the way you want.